Decide if a group is abelian
Let $G = \langle X: R\rangle$ be a finitely presented group. The following problem seems very natural to me, yet I cannot find any reference for it: Decide if $G$ is abelian or not.
With a reduction to the word problem one can show that this is undecidable. However, I would be interested in more details about this.
Does anyone know literature where this problem has been addressed? If not, then why is there so little mention of it?

You mean a reduction from the word problem?

It's basically equivalent to the word problem. To decide if $G$ is abelian, you need to check if every commutator of every pair of generators is trivial, so it's an instance of the word problem on an explicit finite subset. So, for specific positive results, just look up the literature on the word problem in whatever class of groups you happen to be interested in. For undecidabilty results, this is just an instance of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian-Rabin_theorem, since being abelian is a Markov property. I hope this explains why it's not specifically addressed in the literature.

Explicitly: first observe that there is an algorithm $A$ [with input a finite presentation] telling you whether a group has trivial abelianization (word problem within abelian groups). Next, assume by contradiction that some algorithm $B$ tells you whether a group is abelian. Then, since a group is trivial iff it's abelian and has trivial abelianization, running $A$ and $B$ tells you (in particular) whether a group is trivial, and this is known not to exist.
